# Java Generics : Understanding Bounded Wildcards

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, wildcard

In [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) chapter, one sentence got my attention. For the following declaration `List<? extends Shape>`, it says:

> Note: It could be Shape itself, or some subclass; **it need not literally extend Shape**.

What does **not literally** in this context mean ?

Comment: The wording in the tutorial could be better. Is it clearer if it is reworded as ***"it need not directly extend Shape"***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the class does not *have* to `extend Shape`, i.e. be a direct subclass of `Shape`. It could also be `Shape` itself, or it could be an indirect subclass of `Shape`, or `Shape` could be an `interface` which the class `implements`. What the author is trying to convey is that the keyword `extends` is used out of convenience (adding a new keyword to a language is expensive) and familiarity, it does *not* mean that every type that can be used has to have *exactly* the string `extends Shape` in its definition.

In other words: the author *literally* means "literally" with "literally".

Answer (score 2):

`Shape` could be an interface and `<? extends Shape>` could be an instance of a class that implements the `Shape` interface.